# Chinuch of shofar blowing

Tags: halacha, minor-katan-child, chinuch-education, shulchan-aruch, shofar

The following is a quote from the Shulchan Aruch:

> הלכות ראש השנה-סימן תקצו - 
>   תשלום תקיעות לאחר התפלה, ובו סעיף אחד
>
> א. לאחר תפלה מריעים תרועה גדולה בלא תקיעה. הגה: ויש מקומות נוהגין לחזור ולתקוע שלשים קולות (מנהגים ישנים) ולאחר שיצאו בזה שוב אין לתקוע עוד בחנם אבל קטן אפילו הגיע לחינוך מותר לומר לו שיתקע (המגיד פרק ב' מהלכות שופר) ומותר לו לתקוע כל היום (אור זרוע דראש השנה): ‏

Here's what the Mishna Berurah writes:

> ‏{ג} אין לתקוע עוד וכו' - דכיון שא"צ הוי ככל שאר יו"ט שאסור לתקוע משום שבות. ועיין בט"ז שדעתו דיו"ט של ר"ה אינו דומה לשאר יו"ט בזה אבל רוב האחרונים הסכימו לאסור כדברי הרמ"א. ולענין טלטול לכו"ע שרי כל היום דהא ראוי לתקוע בו להוציא אחרים שלא יצאו עדיין:
>   {ד} בחנם - וגם אסור להוציא השופר כשא"צ לתקוע דהוי הוצאה שלא לצורך ועיין סימן תקי"ח ס"א בהג"ה ואפילו מי שיתקע ביום שני אסור לתקוע בראשון להתלמד:
>   {ה} מותר לומר לו שיתקע - היינו אף להשתדל ללמדו אופן התקיעות ואפילו אחר שאינו אביו משמע דמותר בזה דמחנך לקטן:
>   {ו} כל היום - אקטן קאי דאילו גדול הא כבר כתב דאין לתקוע עוד בחנם:‏

In a nutshell, an adult has a certain amount of shofar blasts he may perform, after which he may not blow any more, because of a shvus not to blow. A child however may continue blowing and we call this Chinuch. The achronim 
I.e. the Taz mentioned in the Mishna Berurah,  address the fact that this chinuch of blowing outweighs whatever issue it is that underlies the shvus not to use the shofar.

Here's my question. How is this Chinuch? Consider a child eating Matzah. How many kizaism will he eat before we say that is no longer Chinuch? The child in our case blew five hundred shofar blasts and those were all considered chinuch, are fifty kizeisim all chinuch too? I could give more examples along this line of thought, but I'm sure you got the point.

Comment: I don't quite get the point... Why wouldn't those be considered _chinuch_?

Comment: I'm more interested in the general question of why a child blowing shofar is ANY form of chinuch, even if he blows just 1 blast? I understand that we would need to train a child to eat matzah b/c everyone needs to eat matzah. But, not everyone needs to blow the shofar, so why is there any obligation to teach this to any child? What is the founding concept that there is any chinuch for shofar blowing? To me, this sounds like just a child playing with the shofar, which the SA permits, anyway IIRC.

Comment: @Daniel let's assume like the Ritva in succah and most achronim that chinuch must be a practice of an actual mitzvah. So giving a kid a lemon or a passul esrog on Succos, is not Chinuch. I would assume that just like a situation in which an adult fulfilled a mitzvah and repeats the action, no mitzvah fulfillment is attained, so too there is no chinuch. Of course proving this assumption wrong would be a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Isn't this MB proof that the assumption is wrong?

Comment: @Daniel what do you mean?

Comment: @DanF I was bothered by the child blowing too! Baruch Hashem shekivanti: ) it led me to think of a hindsight Tzarich lomer type of pshat. I'm hoping to hear something more concrete here.

Comment: It is mutar for children to make brachos even without eating anything so they will learn how to make a bracha. (In such a situation one must not answer Amen since it is not a valid bracha) similarly learning how to blow shofar is learning how to perform a mitzvah and is included in the mitzvah of chinuch. And certainly according to Rabenu Tom that the bracha is letkoah not lishmoah this is the case.